# Bootsrap 4 modal is not working in sticky-top navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I used the modal in the sticky-top navbar. But the modal is not properly working. when I remove the sticky-top modal is working.
pasting my  code here:

I used the modal in the sticky-top navbar. But the modal is not properly working. when I remove the sticky-top modal is working.
pasting my  code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<title>Modal</title>

</head>
 <style>


 </style>
<body>

<div class="navbar sticky-top">


   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    <img src="help.jpg">
    </button>


    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Customer Support</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>


</div>









 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is not working either. Please add a relevant code snippet of the problem in the question. Don't expect anyone to dig trough the code of your website. Also it makes the question useless for future reference without code.

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes @SuperDJ

Comment: You think this is a homework website? Provide some code, show us what you've tried. You are lucky @CodeGator answered your question. But wait, there is no question at all.

Comment: Sorry, Sir. I tried to provide code but at that time there is some error.I'm not familiar with this site. Trying to learn how to ask the question and how to add code. Sorry for my mistakes @Tenzolinho

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change position: fixed; to `position: unset;` from .modal-backdrop and you're done...

```css
.modal-backdrop {
  position:unset !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html><head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

 
 
<title>Modal</title>
 
</head>
 
<body class="">
 
<div class="navbar sticky-top">
  
 
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
 <img src="help.jpg">
 </button>


 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
     <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Customer Support</h5>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
       <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
     </button>
      </div>  
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>





 
 
 
 
 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 

</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you :) @CodeGator

Comment: This solution works, however the layers below the modal do not get blurred and greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

Move model code out side navbar.
Modal will work properly with backdrop.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<title>Modal</title>

</head>
 <style>


 </style>
<body>

<div class="navbar sticky-top">


   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    <img src="help.jpg">
    </button>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Customer Support</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>  
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>

 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```